# Isset doesn't detect variable from $_session?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to do a login access in one page but it doesn't seem to work, the isset is not detecting the variable so it's not redirecting to another webpage.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
header("Location:llistat_foto_mulimedia.html");


}
else{
 session_start();
?>

...<html>,form...

  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])){
   require_once 'conexio.php';
   $pdo = new Conexio(); 
   $pdo->exec("set names utf8");

   $dbTabla="autores";



   $consulta=$pdo->prepare("SELECT*FROM $dbTabla WHERE email=?, contrasenya=?");

   $consulta->execute(array($_POST['email'], $_POST['contra']));

   if(!$consulta) {
     echo "Error en realitzar la consulta!!";
   }
   else{
    if($consulta->rowCount() != 1){

      echo "Usuari no existeix\n";
      $_SESSION['id_usuario']=12;

    }

    else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id_usuario']=$consulta->id_autor;


        }

      }


             }
}
?> 
<input type="submit" name="sub"  Value="Acces">
```

......
What I'm doing wrong? what should be the right method to do this?

Comment: start page with session_start(); after that use isset() for session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do `session_start` before anything else:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
    header("Location:llistat_foto_mulimedia.html");
}
else{
    ...
```

Because `session_start` not only creates new session but also resumes existing one. `$_SESSION` array does not exist until you call it. See [documentation](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Comment: Thanks for the help!! the problem now is that the user needs to refresh the page to be redirected after submitting the form

Comment: This is normal : at the first connection `$_SESSION['id_usuario']` is empty, so you don't enter in the first redirect condition.

Comment: Now I'm using en echo ->echo "<script>location.reload();</script>"; to solve this problem but it's a very dirty solution

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read session variables:

```
isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])
```

... until you load a session:

```
session_start()
```

Please have a look at the [Basic Usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) chapter.

Answer (score 0):

You must run `session_start();` before you can access any types of session variables.

Answer (score 0):

Uptill now all answers are right. 
I only want to say that you must start session (session_start();) in your page before any echo or html tag because it is global variable

it is very easy , you should write session_start(); in first line of your page